# Can GWT RPC be used between 2 servers?

Tags: servlets, gwt, gwt-rpc

I'd like to deploy 2 web apps (app1, app2) in two distinct web containers (tomcat1, tomcat2), each running on distinct JVMs and network nodes. App1 is a GWT app.  App2 is server-side java code.  Both app1 server-side and app2 have the same object model.   To send a request from app1 server to app2 for processing I could use HTTP POST, but that would require custom serialization at each end.  Is it possible to use GWT RPC instead; i.e. between 2 distinct GWT servers?  Is there an alternative way to accomplish this?

Comment: Out of curiosity why do you even want to have two seperate web apps for this when you could just do it in 1 ?

Comment: To isolate part of the platform from the internet.

Comment: But you can still do that with a single GWT project. I'd argue that it's actually less secure to keep your back-end in a different project. Because it means you need to expose it so it can be connected to...

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Correct me if I'm wrong, but by forwarding the request to another server, I (a) don't have to put high value code on a potentially exposed platform, and (b) I can add network security (e.g., filtering) on the connection between the GWT server and the remote server. The remote app becomes just a java project with servlet access. Similar perhaps to RMI/HTTP.

Comment: Yeah that's true

Answer (score -1):

It's possible and it's what I did,

Remember to allow cross-origin-request in your App2 (server-side java code)

Comment: The question is about "app1 server" making calls to app2, not the app1 GWT app making cross-origin requests.

Comment: Thomas, could you share your insight on this issue? I ended up creating a class HttpCallback implements RequestCallback and serializing the payload.